# Function already is declared but where?

Tags: c++

I wrote some Code and I got a lot of errors which i cant explain to myself i already googled a lot but i cant find answers.
It says my main() ist already declared and some identifiers arent. but I dont know why. thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CPlanung.h"
#include "CBuchung.h"

using namespace std;

CPlanung cp;

CMaschine Maschinen[5] = {
    Maschinen[0] = CMaschine(1, "Drehbank"),
    Maschinen[1] = CMaschine(2, "Fräser"),  
    Maschinen[2] = CMaschine(3, "Schleifmaschine"),
    Maschinen[3] = CMaschine(4, "Automat 1"),
    Maschinen[4] = CMaschine(5, "Automat 2")
};

CProjekt Projekt[10] = {
    
    Projekt[0] = CProjekt(1, "Winkel"),
    Projekt[1] = CProjekt(2, "Strebe"),
    Projekt[2] = CProjekt(3, "Stütze"),
    Projekt[3] = CProjekt(4, "Halterung"),
    Projekt[4] = CProjekt(5, "Winkel"),
    Projekt[5] = CProjekt(6, "Sockel"),
    Projekt[6] = CProjekt(7, "Abdeckung"),
    Projekt[7] = CProjekt(8, "Befestigung"),
    Projekt[8] = CProjekt(9, "Anschluss"),
    Projekt[9] = CProjekt(10, "Lager")

};



int main()
{

    cp.StartProjekt();

    return 0;
}

//Klasse Buchung.h

#pragma once
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "CProjekt.h"
#include "CPlanung.h"
#include "Maschinenplanung_Marco.cpp"

using namespace std;

class CBuchung
{
protected:
    struct Buchung {
        int _maschine;
        int _projekt;
        int _beginn;
        int _ende;
    }_buchungen[200] = { {3, 1, 1, 1},{4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 2, 5}, {3, 1, 4, 5},{3, 5, 5, 6},{3,1,10,11}, {3,2,11,11} }, buchung;
    //vector<Buchung> _bookings;
    bool existsMasch, existsBeginn, existsProj, exists;
    int n, temp, sum;
public:

    CBuchung(); //Konstruktor

    void Buchen(int Maschine, int Projekt, int Beginn, int Ende); // weist einem Projekt eine Maschine mit dem angegebenen Beginn und Ende zu

    void Stornieren(int Maschine, int Projekt, int Beginn, int Ende);   //löscht die Buchung einer Maschine für ein Projekt in dem angegebenen zusammenhängenden Zeitraum

    void getBuchungenProj(int Projekt);

    void getBuchungenMasch(int Maschine);

    void Belegung();
};


//Klasse CPlanung.h

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "CMaschine.h"
#include "CProjekt.h"
#include "CBuchung.h"
#include "Maschinenplanung_Marco.cpp"
using namespace std;

class CPlanung
{

protected:
    int wahl, maschinenWahl, projektWahl, beginn, ende;


public:

    CPlanung();

    void StartProjekt(void);        //initiiert das Programm und beinhaltet das Hauptmenue

    void Buchen(void);              //weist einem Programm eine Maschine zu gemäß der Beschreibung Menü 1

    void Stornieren(void);          //löscht die Zuweisung einer Maschine zu einem Projekt gemäß der Beschreibung in Menü 2

    void Projektliste(void);        //zeigt die Buchung von Maschinen für ein Projekt gemäß Beschreibung in Menü 3

    void Maschinenliste(void);      //zeigt die Buchung für welch Projekte eine Maschine gebucht ist gemäß Beschreibung in Menü 4

    void Belegung(void);            //zeigt eine Übersicht der Maschinenbelegungen für die Projekte gemäß Beschreibung in Menü 5

    void Doppelbelegung(void);      //untersucht, ob eine Maschine gleichzeitig für mehrere Projekte verplant ist gemäß Beschreibung in Menü 6
    


};
```

Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler  C2065   "cp": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner  MaschinenPlanung_Marco  C:\Users\danie\source\repos\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\Maschinenplanung_Marco.cpp    36

Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler  C2374   "Maschinen": Neudefinition; Mehrfachinitialisierung MaschinenPlanung_Marco  C:\Users\danie\source\repos\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\Maschinenplanung_Marco.cpp    9

Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler  C2084   Funktion "int main(void)" hat bereits einen Funktionsrumpf  MaschinenPlanung_Marco  C:\Users\danie\source\repos\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\Maschinenplanung_Marco.cpp    34

Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler  C2084   Funktion "int main(void)" hat bereits einen Funktionsrumpf  MaschinenPlanung_Marco  C:\Users\danie\source\repos\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\MaschinenPlanung_Marco\Maschinenplanung_Marco.cpp    34

I just want to initilise some global objects and start the Menue from the main.

Comment: please add the complete compiler error message in the question

Comment: i'd advise to program in english, and to use english versions of your development tools. this will make getting help when you have problems much easier,

Answer (score 2):

What is this in `CPlanung.h` and `CBuchung.h`?

```
#include "Maschinenplanung_Marco.cpp"
```

Never include a cpp file. Assuming this is the file with your `main` then that is the explanation for the error.

Comment: man i love u that was the mistake. but now if i want to use the object cp which is declared now before the main, global. i cant use it in CBuchen why

Comment: @Daniel You need to put `extern CPlanung cp;` in one of your header files (whichever one is being included before you try to use `cp`).

Comment: done this but now it says undeclared identifier

Comment: or missing type specifier. `extern CPlanung cp;` thats the code i wrote in CPlanung.h out of Protected or public

Comment: @Daniel Well `extern CPlanung cp;` has to go after the declaration of the class `CPlanung`, not inside the class, not before the class.